# Physics bodies keep falling away from the sprite node

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to create nodes, that are put into an array, and then are added to the scene with their physics bodies.

Here is the code for creating the initial sprites:

```
            let name = createTarget()
            let targetNode = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: name)
            targetNode.name = name

            chickenNodes.append(targetNode)
            targetNode.position = generateRandomLocation()

            let range = SKRange(lowerLimit: targetNode.position.y, upperLimit: targetNode.position.y)
            let lockToCenter = SKConstraint.positionY(range)
            targetNode.constraints = [lockToCenter]

            if movingItems { animateTargets(targetNode) }
```

Once all of these nodes are in the array, I add them in didMove to a background node, fgNode, in the scene, like this:

```
for chicken in chickenNodes {
        let texture = SKTexture(imageNamed: chicken.name!)
        chicken.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(texture: texture, size: texture.size())
        chicken.physicsBody?.isDynamic = true
        chicken.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = true
        chicken.physicsBody?.allowsRotation = false
        chicken.physicsBody?.linearDamping = 0.0
        chicken.physicsBody?.restitution = 1.0
        chicken.physicsBody?.friction = 0.0
        fgNode.addChild(chicken)
    }
```

When I view the physics through the scene, the physics bodies keep falling away from the sprite (as though they're responding to the gravity in the scene); and the sprite is just locked where it is. How do I ensure that the physicsBody sticks to the sprite?

Comment: You need to have a node as `isDynamic=false` to which other nodes should stick.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by that? What other node and where should that go?